# In Eclipse, how do I use Navigator to look at files outside my workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to use Eclipe's handy Navigator panel to browse files -- e.g. library files -- outside of my workspace. Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways, although these are a bit of a kludge:

1. Create a new General project.  When you enter the project name (make one up), uncheck the "use default location" checkbox.  Use the browse button to navigate to the directory (or a parent directory) containing the files you want to browse and select that directory.  When you click finish, the project will appear in your Navigator view with the files in the directory appearing in the project.  You can now act on those files with the available Eclipse tools. Note that when you act on a file in this directory you are acting on the original file, not a copy.
2. You can import (Import --> File System) some number of files into an existing Eclipse directory.  Note that unlike the above approach, this will copy those files into the project, where ever that happens to be.  You can, however, use available Eclipse tools on those copies.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your first method is perfect -- gets the libraries into the same panel as my project, which is even better than having it in the separate navigator panel.